# texture coordinates for point in polygon

Tags: graphics, 3d, polygon, textures

I have a polygon, where each vertex has texture coordinates. How can I calculate texture coord for any point lying in the polygon? (I know points coordinates.)
Thanks

p.s. sorry for my english...

Answer (score 1):

I you don't care about perspective than it's simple enough. simply find the barycentric coordinates of the point and do a linear interpolation of the vertices texture coordinates. [Here's a nice tutorial about this](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html)

If however you're trying to do this in a scene where with a perspective projection, you'll probably want to worry about perspective correction as well. [Here's some reading about this issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping#Perspective_correctness)